# How does Oracle handle two users writing to the same table?

Tags: oracle

Two users have done different insert operation in same schema and same table,  which values will committed in the table? Which value inserted?

**jack user**

```
insert into sample values(10);
```

**ram user**

```
Insert into sample values(20);
```

Comment: Both will be inserted as long as there are no constraint violations or other database errors. Neither will be committed unless you explicitly issue a `COMMIT` or your client issues it for you (e.g. SQL*Plus will commit when you exit).

Answer (score 1):

Both will be inserted.  Oracle is an enterprise database, built to handle systems with countless users.  How could it do that if only one person can inserted into a table at a time?

Obviously there's a lot of engineering in Oracle's resource management, to ensure that each user's work can be saved without blocking other users.  Read about locking in [the Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT88970).